# Using Python requests library on a virtual machine with jupyterhub is extremely slow

Tags: python, ipython, python-requests, jupyter, jupyterhub

I setup a virtual machine with Jupyterhub. When I want to get use the requests package i is extremely slow.
When doing the flowing:

```
import logging
import requests

logging.basicConfig() # you need to initialize logging, otherwise you will not see anything from requests
logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
requests_log = logging.getLogger("requests.packages.urllib3")
requests_log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
requests_log.propagate = True

session = requests.Session()

response = session.get("http://www.google.de")
```

I get this Debugging messages

```
DEBUG:requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTP connection (1): www.google.de
DEBUG:requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool:http://www.google.de:80 "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 4477
```

I've to wait more than a minute between the both debugging messages.

When I run the same code on my local machine with a regular Jupyter setup (using anaconda) it works without any problem.

I could imagine I did something wrong with the network settings, but I can't locate the problem.

Thanks for your help.

UPDATE:
I tested urllib3 - same problem. When I use regular python via bash, it work just fine, when I use ipython via bash it is very slow.

Comment: Thoughts : try the same thing in a Jupyter Docker container

Comment: I wanted to avoid docler. It means a management overhead for me because I am not very familiar with docker. I tried it once, it did not ended with a  satisfing result.

Comment: It's just a thought... The problem sounds like some network interface issue in the vm

Comment: That was my thought too. But than: Why it works in python but not in in ipython? Grinds my gears. :/

Comment: Good point... What about a virtualenv?

Comment: My setup is the following: I ve a conda virtual envorinment on my host system where I develop the project and test it. The same environment is installed on the vm. I deploy the code to the vm where I have a jupyterhub which is using the environment. As I am investigating the issue, I am using python and ipython via terminal but still using this environment.